# Amazon SageMaker deploying from model artifacts - what object do we load from archive?

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst). It shows how to deploy directly from model artifacts:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlowModel

tf_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data='s3://mybucket/model.tar.gz',
                           role='MySageMakerRole',
                           entry_point='entry.py',
                           name='model_name')

predictor = tf_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge')
```

I am curious what kind of object is stored in `s3://mybucket/model.tar.gz`? Is it tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec or tf.estimator.Estimator or something else? Is there example how to build and store this object?

Answer (score 2):

The model.tar.gz is the `SavedModel` or the output of the training stage. You can generate this file from every source that is able to train a TF model, including SageMaker training jobs (see [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own/tensorflow_bring_your_own.ipynb) for example), Colab etc.